# I can't upload files on my Django's website

Tags: django, django-admin

I have created an online store in Django. It works well on my pc. I have moved it on shared hosting, but now I can't upload anything. I can add new information in database but without images.

I always get the 404 error. I have MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT configured corectly in settings.

Who know how to fix this issues?

Comment: Permissions on the server media directories? You need to provide a bit more details.

Comment: just to confirm the `DEBUG` mode is now False, right?

Comment: DEBUG is True. Media directories has 755 permission.

Comment: Change `DEBUG` to `False`

Comment: Changed, now i get the error The requested URL /admin/app/image/add/ was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

My settings.py file(this is my first experience with django and python):

"""

```
Django settings for public project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'public.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'public.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = "/home/scrisoft/public_html/bushare/app/static/media/"
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "http://bushare.scrisoft.com/app/static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/home/scrisoft/public_html/bushare/app/static/',
)
```

The address of my website is http://bushare.scrisoft.com/

Comment: Webserver config? If it's working on the website with django runserver, it's probably webserver

Comment: what is: $ ls -l /home/scrisoft/public_html/bushare/app/static/media/?

Comment: is the folder where are uploaded all images.

Comment: copy-pate here the ls -l output

Comment: My models.py:

    from __future__ import unicode_literals
    from django.db import models
    
    def upload_to(instance, filename):
        return 'app/static/media/%s' % (filename)
    
    class Image(models.Model):
        name = models.TextField()
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to,null = True, blank = True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

Answer (score 0):

I have got this error because I have used postgressql database on my pc, but on hosting i have created manually a mysql database. Now i have solved this error by move this app on hosting with postgressql support.